# android: SQLite Db error

Tags: android, database, sqlite

hello i am building a SQLite Db for my android application . this is the code :

```
package com.example.pap_e;



import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class FeedsDbAdapter {

    private final Context mCtx;
    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "RSSDatabase";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DB_NAME = "rss_data";
    public static String TABLE = "list";
    public static final String ID = "_id";
    public static final String RSS = "_rss";
    public static final String TITLE = "_title";
    public static final String PUBDATE = "_pubdate";
    public static final String DESCRIPTION = "_description";
    public static final String LINK = "_link";
    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;



    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        }


        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("CREATE_TABLE"+TABLE+"("+ID+ "integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+RSS+"text NOT NULL,"
                    +TITLE+"text NOT NULL,"+PUBDATE+"text NOT NULL,"+DESCRIPTION+"text NOT NULL,"+LINK+"text NOT NULL"+")");
        }
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE);
            onCreate(db);}

    }
    public FeedsDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {

        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
        }
        public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
        }

        public boolean updateAnakoinosi(long rowId, String rss, String title,
                String pubdate, String description, String link) {
                ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
                args.put(RSS, rss);
                args.put(TITLE, title);
                args.put(PUBDATE, pubdate);
                args.put(DESCRIPTION, description);
                args.put(LINK, link);
                return mDb.update(TABLE, args, ID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;}
                public Cursor fetchAllAnakoinoseis() {
                return mDb.query(TABLE, new String[] { ID, RSS, TITLE, PUBDATE,
                DESCRIPTION,LINK }, null, null, null, null, null); }



}
```

The thing is that i get an error at `public class FeedsDbAdapter` that says:"The blank final field mCtx may not have been initialized" but i had it initialized using `private final Context mCtx;` Am i missing something here ? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't initialize the context yet. You have to initialize it inside FeedsDbAdapter constructor like :

```
public FeedsDbAdapter (Context context){

       mCtx = context;
     }
```

first declare FeedsDbAdapter constructor, because you use FeedsDbAdapter  class through its constructor in other classes ans the other activity context will assign to this current context.

Comment: glad to help you ..all the best.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to :

```
private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);

        mCtx = context;
    }
```

Comment: I did what you told me to do but the error wasn't fixed.Also it displayed an error at `mCtx = context;` that says:"Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field mCtx"

Answer (score 0):

This question of yours relates to java. This line `private final Context mCtx;` is just a declaration of field mCtx of type context. And as this field has been declared as final, It has to be iniliazed inside the constructor `mCtx = context;`. Even if mCtx is not declared as final, it has still to be initialized before being used.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because your class is static... Remove static from your class and change your code to

```
DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    mCtx = context;
}
```